# How to add attribute to describe() in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, attributes, describe

`df.describe().loc[['mean','std','25%','50%','75%']]`

How to add other attributes, for instance percentile 10% and 90% to the default output attribute from describe() function is?

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter `percentiles` in [`DataFrame.describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

> **percentiles** : list-like of numbers, optional
>   The percentiles to include in the output. All should fall between 0 and 1. The default is [.25, .5, .75], which returns the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentiles.

```
df.describe(percentiles=[.1, .25, .5, .75, .9])
```